# Can I create a radar chart of sunrise/sunset times for a year

Tags: plotting, astronomy

Can I create a radar chart (or just a simple curve) of sunrise/sunset times, for a given location thougout a year?

It would be something like this, but with a smooth curve:
[image: example]
<sub>(source: [hassanhameed.com](http://www.hassanhameed.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/namaadhuburu.png))</sub>

Can it be done in WolframAlpha? Or do I need *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 20):

Download and learn [Package for Radar Charts](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/762950).

```
Import["http://tinyurl.com/ntmhkca"]
```

Load package:

```
Needs["RadarChart`"]
```

Consider this year on monthly period (you can do any period):

```
month = DateRange[DateObject[{2016}], DateObject[{2017}], 
        Quantity[1, "Months"]]
```

and a function

```
f[l_] := N[l[[1]] + l[[2]]/60]
```

Get the data

```
set = f[TimeObject[Sunset[
       GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]],
       #]][[1]]] & /@ month

rise = f[TimeObject[Sunrise[
       GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]],
       #]][[1]]] & /@ month
```

Plot it

```
RadarChart[{set, rise}, 
ChartLegends -> {"SUNSET", "SUNRISE"}, 
AxesLabel -> DateString /@ month, 
Filling -> Axis, 
PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}]
```

[image]

Now, getting everything together, **and taking in account TIME ZONE**, code with help of @JasonB, see comments:

```
Needs["RadarChart`"]

sunRadarChart[city_, year_: Automatic, timezone_: Automatic] :=

 Module[{month, set, rise, yr, tz, f, place},

  place = Interpreter["City"][city];
  f[l_] := N[l[[1]] + l[[2]]/60];
  tz = timezone /. Automatic -> LocalTimeZone[place];
  yr = year /. Automatic -> (First@DateList[]);
  month = DateRange[DateObject[{yr}], DateObject[{yr + 1}], Quantity[1, "Months"]];
  set = f[TimeObject[Sunset[GeoPosition[place], #, TimeZone -> tz]][[1]]] & /@ month;
  rise = f[TimeObject[Sunrise[GeoPosition[place], #, TimeZone -> tz]][[1]]] & /@ month;

  RadarChart[{set, rise}, AxesLabel -> (DateString[#, "MonthRomanNumeral"] & /@ month),
   Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}, ImageSize -> 220,
   AxesLabel -> (DateString[#, "MonthRomanNumeral"] & /@ month),
   PlotLabel -> CommonName@place, ChartLegends -> False]]

ParallelMap[sunRadarChart, 
{"Boston", "Nome, USA", "Rio Gallegos, Argentina", "Cape Town", 
  "Dunedin, New Zealand", "Tokio", "Dubai", "Fargo, USA", "Nairobi"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice package, +1. Only one issue: `weeks` is not defined.

Comment: Excellent post Vitaliy.  Should that be `DateString /@ months` in the last line?  I took this and wrapped it into a [function](http://pastebin.com/raw/mQ3bGFJt) so that it would be easy to compare different cities.  It's really striking if you compare Honolulu with Helsinki  :-)  I had to pay attention to the `TimeZone` as when I did Los Angeles originally it had the red circle larger.

Comment: Bug fixed, thanks guys.

Comment: If you have daily data, the `AxesLabel` gets a bit crowded. I used: `AxesLabel -> (DateString /@ day /. x_ /; StringQ[x] \[And] (StringSplit[x, " "][[2]] != "1" \[Or] StringSplit[x, " "][[4]] != "2016") -> "")`

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov - I like the `Interpreter["City"]`, now I don't have to look up the state/region to plot a city.  But I still think it's important to call on `TimeZone`.  Using your updated code, I get [different results](http://i.imgur.com/GkXlIiH.png) from you, and the ones you get for Dunedin are similar to mine for Fargo, neither makes sense.

Comment: But using the `TimeZone` option, (my [updated adaptation of your code here](http://pastebin.com/raw/5s9NkSSy)), I'm able to get [these results](http://i.imgur.com/tTzrNdq.png) which I think make more sense.

Comment: It's a bit disturbing that all the results are relative to the the same time zone, and not to the local time zone of each country (so sunsets can occur before sunrises !). To correct that, one just needs to set the `TimeZone` option to the same Entity city (e.g. for Tokyo `TimeZone->Entity["City", List["Tokyo", "Tokyo", "Japan"]]`

Comment: @JasonB same comment than you !

Comment: @JasonB cool thanks updated.